# Naming columns in a data table in R

Tags: r, data.table

I have two data table, D1 and D2. D1 is 20 by 181 and D2 is 181 by 1. I want to change the name of D1 columns to the values in D2. I am using the following code but I'm getting an error:

```
for(i in 1 : ncol(D1) ){ names(D1)[i] <- c("D2[i,1]")
```

Error: object of type 'closure' is not subsettable.

Could you please tell me what should I do to make it work?

Comment: Take out the quotes. And wrapping the expression in `c(.)` just shows a lack of understanding R syntax. Doesn't hurt, but is not needed. This would have been more direct: `names(D1) <- D2[1:ncol(D1)]`

Comment: You should use `setnames` if they are `data.table`s

Comment: Or use `setNames`, although I usually use it in a function when I'm wrapping it around a list to return, since `names<-` seems a bit more compact.

Comment: If these are actual `data.table`-objects tehn teh correct tag would be "data.table". If they are not then the 'table' and 'data' tags should be removed.

Comment: @BondedDust, It did not work!

Comment: @Richard Scriven, I did search on setnames, but there is no example such as mine.

Comment: Please clarify this question before responding with vague complaints. IS THIS A `data.table`??? "Did not work" really has no value when doing programming since the number of failure modes is countably infinite.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I don't word with data tables, but this is a solution that would work for data frames, and should hopefully generalize. The strategy is to use the fact that you can fill one vector with another vector, without ever having to use a loop.

```
 # make the example data sets
 D1 <- as.data.frame(matrix(data=(1:(20*181)), nrow=20, ncol=181))
 D2 <- data.frame(name=paste0("Name_",(1:181)))

 # make a copy of D1
 D1_named <- D1

 # the vector of D1 names is replaced by the value in D2
 # (both vectors must be of the same length)
 names(D1_named) <- D2$name
```

Comment: It did not work for data table. I changed my tables to data frame.